# Increasing kernel CPU usage on web server running node on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, next.js, cpu-usage, express-session, ubuntu-20.04

I have a problem with increasing kernel cpu usage on a web server I am running. On a 6 core cpu the kernel usage increases from 5 to 50% in some 8 hours.

I have noticed it takes less time when there are more active users on the site and I don't have this problem in dev, therefore I don't have any code that can reproduce the problem. I am hoping for some advice how to troubleshoot this though, what should I investigate to figure out what the problem is?

"pm2 restart" will take the cpu usage down so this is what I need to do every 8 hours or so. I have also noticed increasing cpu usage of systemd-resolved up to some 50% in 8 hours but restarting it with "systemctl restart systemd-resolved" will not help.

I am running it on ubuntu 20.04, node v12.19.0, next 9.5.3, express, express-session, express-socket.io.session, mongodb etc. I have had this problem even on older versions of all this though.

Comment: It's possible somebody on https://askubuntu.com/ may have some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will wait some time more to see if I get some suggestions here though!